# How do friends come to my ftb server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a friend with the same modpack as me, and I have the feed the beast server.  How does my freind join?  Do I need to port forward differently than in vanilla?

Comment: nope should be exactly the same as vanilla besides that configs need to match

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly the same as in vanilla, however, now you have to make sure that in addition to using the same version of Minecraft, that they are using the same version of the Modpacks as well.  This can lead to annoying compatibility issues, so everyone has to make sure that everything is updated properly and the server files are configured properly to allow the connections.